# Get record from table against a specific day of current week

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I want to know the SQL Server query in which I can get record from the table against the specific day (like Monday OR Tuesday) of current week, OR against the specific day from the last 7 days.

Like I want to get record for 1st day of last 7 days OR Like I want to get record for the Monday OR Tuesday from current week.

By the way I can get specific day of current week through this SQL Server query

```
      //Query
      SELECT DATEADD(DD, 0 - DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()), GETDATE())  //Get Sunday
      SELECT DATEADD(DD, 1 - DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()), GETDATE())  //Get Monday
      SELECT DATEADD(DD, 2 - DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()), GETDATE())  //Get Tuesday
```

But I want to get record from the table against these days, like so:

```
      Select * from tbl_Sale where date = "Here the specific day's date should be called"
```

Sorry for the long text but I really need to explain that what I need to do, so please if anyone can do this?

Comment: Take a look at [DATEFIRST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Return only those records where **date** is in the last 7 days and then further restrict your criteria to just Mondays.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_Sale 
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), date) BETWEEN -7 AND 0
  AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY, date) = 'Monday'
```

This would also work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_Sale 
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), date) BETWEEN -7 AND 0
  AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, date) = 2 -- by default 2 is equivalent to Monday
```

You will find a lot of valuable information reading up on [Date and Time Data Types and Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). So by default, `DATEPART(WEEKDAY, date)` will return 1 for any Sunday, 2 for any Monday, etc. However, you can set the first of the week to be whatever day you want by setting [DATEFIRST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Here is some [sample code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cfb572ba33f38c6ef85440315f62bb28) to show the Weekday Names and Weekday Numbers for a range of dates.

Comment: Your answer is valuable, great and thank you. For DATENAME by name of Day its working fine, DATEPART is also working fine but I want to know what is the DATEPART for Monday? Like if I write DATEPART(WEEKDAY, dt) = 3 what will be the exact day name of 3?

Comment: My answer has a couple of mistakes as I was writing and testing my query against a local table of mine. I will edit my answer.